# How to find a basis for the hyperplane given with the equation $x + y + z - w = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I tried the following :
$x = - y - z + w $ so we can express every vector $(x, y, z, w)$ as
$(x, y, z, w) = (-y -z + w, y, z, w) = y(-1, 1, 0, 0) + z(-1, 0, 1, 0) + w(1, 0, 0, 1)$

so the basis vectors are : $(-1, 1, 0, 0)^T$, $(-1, 0, 1, 0)^T$, $(1, 0, 0, 1)^T$

Does this make sense? Is that really the basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense. Right now you are saying that any vector on the hyperplane is a linear combination of these $3$ vectors. It is indeed the basis once you verify that they are linearly independent.

> Although you will later realize that verifying linear independence in these kinds of questions is not required. Linear independence is implied because if we assume$$y(-1, 1, 0, 0) + z(-1, 0, 1, 0) + w(1, 0, 0, 1)=(0,0,0,0)$$then we know the LHS is $(x,y,z,w)$. Thus we directly get $(x,y,z,w)=(0,0,0,0)$ or $y=z=w=0$, implying linear independence.